# Inject object into App in scala main

Tags: scala, dependency-injection, guice

Here is the code:

```
import akka.actor.ActorSystem
import akka.stream.ActorMaterializer
import akka.stream.scaladsl.Sink
import com.google.inject.Inject
import org.bytedeco.javacv.{CanvasFrame, Frame}

class WebCamWindow @Inject()(webCam: WebCam) {

  implicit val system = ActorSystem()
  implicit val materializer = ActorMaterializer()

  val canvas = new CanvasFrame("Webcam")
  //  Set Canvas frame to close on exit
  canvas.setDefaultCloseOperation(javax.swing.JFrame.EXIT_ON_CLOSE)

  val imageDimensions = Dimensions(width = 640, height = 480)
  val webcamSource = webCam.source

  val graph = webcamSource
    .map(MediaConversion.toMat) // most OpenCV manipulations require a Matrix
    .map(Flip.horizontal)
    .map(MediaConversion.toFrame) // convert back to a frame
    .map(canvas.showImage)
    .to(Sink.ignore)

  def run(): Unit = {
    graph.run()
  }
}
```

I would like to make this an App object and run it, but I don't know how to deal with the dependency injection here. Could anyone help?

Full project can be found here: https://bitbucket.org/kindlychung/testscalacv

Comment: your "full project" link says "Access denied" btw

Comment: Ah, sorry. Bitbucket is private by default. It's public now. Thanks!

Answer (score 1, accepted):

First step is to make it into a trait (just for convenience):

```
trait WebCamWindowLike  {
   def webCam: WebCam

   implicit val system ...//all the code is here

}
```

Then you can have old injectable `WebCamWindow`:

```
class WebCamWindow @Inject()(val webCam: WebCam) extends WebCamWindowLike
```

As well as independent runnable object:

```
object WebCamWindowApp extends App with WebCamWindowLike {
   private val injector = Guice.createInjector(new AppInjectory())
   override val webCam = injector.getInstance(classOf[WebCam])
   run()
}
```

Where `AppInjectory extends AbstractModule` is your actual injectory for Guice that takes care of all of your dependencies.

Another option is (if you want to get rid of Guice) manual "injection":

```
object WebCamWindowApp extends App with WebCamWindowLike {

   override val webCam = new WebCam(...)
   run()

}
```

Comment: `WebCam.class` should be `classOf[WebCam]`